Issues applying JSON body filters in EU F&T Portal SEARCH API with WordPress integration
I am trying to use the SEARCH API service of the EU F&T Portal public REST APIs for retrieving data for further integration with my project, but I am having some problems. I am using WordPress as CMS with a plugin called ACF|Advanced Custom Fields. The purpose of the system is to make an API call, retrieve all the results and store each parameter in a custom field and not have to constantly make API calls. According to the API documentation (Funding & Tenders Portal Application Programming Interfaces (APIs)), )), it says that ‘Search criteria (query) can be send in the “Form Data” of the POST request in JSON format’ but I am having trouble implementing the filter in WordPress. The documentation specifies how to get the query for the filter, so what I want to apply would be something like this:
{"bool":{"must":[{"terms":{"type":["1","2","8"]}},{"terms":{"status":["31094501","31094502"]}}]}}

So I would only get responses whose status is 31094501 (Forthcoming) or 31094502 (Open for submission). But when I make the API call, sometimes I get no results and sometimes I get results that do not match the filter applied. I have tried to apply the filter in this way:
add_action('init', 'register_EUopportunity');

function register_EUopportunity() {
    register_post_type('opportunity', [
        'label' => 'EU opportunities',
        'public' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
    ]);
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_opportunities_from_api', 'get_opportunities_from_api');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_opportunities_from_api', 'get_opportunities_from_api');

function get_opportunities_from_api() {
    $current_page = ( ! empty($_POST['current_page']) ) ? $_POST['current_page'] : 1;
    $opportunities = [];
    
    $body = array(
        'bool' => array(
            'must' => array(
                array(
                    'terms' => array(
                        'type' => array('1', '2', '8')
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'terms' => array(
                        'status' => array('31094501', '31094502')
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    $args = array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ),
        'body' => json_encode($body),
    );

    $response = wp_remote_post('https://api.tech.ec.europa.eu/search-api/prod/rest/search?apiKey=SEDIA&text=***&pageSize=50&pageNumber=' . $current_page, $args);
    
    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        return false;
    }
    
    $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    $response_body = json_decode($response_body, true);
    
    if (!is_array($response_body) || empty($response_body['results'])) {
        return false;
    }
    
    $opportunities = $response_body['results'];
    
    foreach ($opportunities as $opportunity) {
        $opportunity_slug = sanitize_title($opportunity['reference']);
        $inserted_opportunity = wp_insert_post([
            'post_name' => $opportunity_slug,
            'post_title' => $opportunity_slug,
            'post_type' => 'opportunity',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        ]);
        
        if (is_wp_error($inserted_opportunity)) {
            continue;
        }
        
        $fillable = [
            'field_6708df10da74e' => 'reference',
            'field_6708d325a3d11' => 'url',
            'field_6708d52fe3556' => 'summary',
            'field_6708f69748573' => 'frameworkProgramme',
            'field_670901cfc55e8' => 'deadlineDate',
            'field_67090647166a6' => 'callTitle',
            'field_67090684813cd' => 'identifier',
            'field_6709088554ec8' => 'descriptionByte',
            'field_670f704b8482f' => 'status',
        ];
        
        foreach ($fillable as $key => $name) {
            if ($name === 'frameworkProgramme' && !empty($opportunity['metadata']['frameworkProgramme'])) {
                update_field($key, $opportunity['metadata']['frameworkProgramme'][0], $inserted_opportunity); 
            } elseif($name === 'deadlineDate' && !empty($opportunity['metadata']['deadlineDate'])){
                update_field($key, $opportunity['metadata']['deadlineDate'][0], $inserted_opportunity);
            } elseif($name === 'callTitle' && !empty($opportunity['metadata']['callTitle'])){
                update_field($key, $opportunity['metadata']['callTitle'][0], $inserted_opportunity);
            } elseif($name === 'identifier' && !empty($opportunity['metadata']['identifier'])){
                update_field($key, $opportunity['metadata']['identifier'][0], $inserted_opportunity);
            } elseif($name === 'descriptionByte' && !empty($opportunity['metadata']['descriptionByte'])){
                update_field($key, $opportunity['metadata']['descriptionByte'][0], $inserted_opportunity);
            } elseif($name === 'status' && !empty($opportunity['metadata']['status'])){
                update_field($key, $opportunity['metadata']['status'][0], $inserted_opportunity);
            } elseif (!empty($opportunity[$name])) {
                update_field($key, $opportunity[$name], $inserted_opportunity);
            }
        }
    }
    
    $current_page = $current_page + 1;
    wp_remote_post(admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=get_opportunities_from_api'), [
        'blocking' => false,
        'sslverify' => false,
        'body' => [
            'current_page' => $current_page
        ]
    ]);
}

If I do not apply any filters, the code seems to work fine. The results are received, added as posts and the custom fields are filled in. But when I apply the filters, what I should get are only results whose status is 31094501 or 31094502, but as I said before, it seems that the filter does not work and sometimes I get no results and sometimes I get results whose status is different from 31094501 or 31094502.
What could be happening? I have also tried using exactly the same filter in POSTMAN. There everything works fine and the expected results are obtained. But in WordPress it does not seem to work.

I think it's better to not double post and that everybody answer on SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79103059/issues-applying-json-body-filters-in-eu-ft-portal-search-api-with-wordpress-int

Sure! Totally agree, my bad. I did not know about the WordPress Developement community in StackExchange and did not know if it could cause any conflicts. As my problem is related to WordPress, I wanted to make the post in the right place. Sorry for the inconvenience, it was totally my fault.
